# am get an error unexpected end of file while executing this code

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash b.sh
for i in $(cat  ~/.supplier_details.csv ) loop

do

v_supplier=`awk -F "," '{print $1} $i`
v_supplier_name=`awk -F "," '{print $2} $i`
v_supplier_address=`awk -F "," '{print $3} $i`

checking_non_numeric=`echo $v_supplier|grep -i [A-z]|wc -l`
checking_numeric=`echo $v_supplier_name|grep [0-9]|wc -l`


if [ $checking_non_numeric -gt 0 ]

then

echo " error: Invalid data for supplier  "

else 

sqlplus -s user/password@database << EOF

create table t(supplier number);

insert into t(supplier)

 values( $v_supplier);

exit ;
EOF ;

fi

if [ $checking_numeric -gt 0 ]

then

echo " error: Invalid data for supplier name  "

else 

sqlplus -s user/password@database << EOF

alter table t1 add  supplier_name varchar2(50) ;

insert into t(supplier_name)

 values( $v_supplier_name);

exit;
EOF;

fi
sqlplus -s user/password@database << EOF

alter table t1 add supplier_address varchar2(100);

insert into t(supplier_address)

 values($supplier_address)
exit;

EOF;

done
```

Comment: Run this code through http://www.shellcheck.net and fix the things it complains about. It finds your problems.

Comment: shebang should be `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/bash b.sh`.

Comment: but after changing it it giving the same error

Comment: this code is regarding to take an input from a csv file which having three column need to check.it will check the first two column if its non-numeric then it will update the table.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 6 through 8 have an unpaired single quote in the awk command.

Should be

```
v_supplier=`awk -F "," '{print $1}' $i`
v_supplier_name=`awk -F "," '{print $2}' $i`
v_supplier_address=`awk -F "," '{print $3}' $i`
```

Comment: After changing it also getting the same error" line 67: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Comment: As mentioned by Etan, Run this code through shellcheck.net and fix the things it complains about. It finds your problems